# Properly resizing both JScrollPane and it's content

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, zooming

I am building a small java application that deals with taking screenshots.
I have a custom class that inherits from JPanel called ScreenshotPanel that holds the image, and it is inside a JScrollPane. The ScrollPane moves and resizes when the frame is resized.
All works well except the zoom part, I want to be able to control the size of the screenshotPanel inside the ScrollPane, however the screenshotPanel doesn't resize, it flickers at the right size for a moment but then it's being resized back to the ScrollPane size.

If I use the screenshotPanel without the ScrollPane it works exactly right, but I want it to automatically add scrollers so you can see move the image around while zoomed-in.

Here is the part of the code I use to resize:

```
    double AR=((double)screenshotPanel.getImage().getHeight())/screenshotPanel.getImage().getWidth();

    screenshotPanel.setSize((int)((getWidth()-180)*zoomFactor), (int)((AR*(getWidth()-180)-100)*zoomFactor));
    scrollPane.setSize(getWidth()-180, (int)(AR*(getWidth()-180))-100);
```

the -180 and -100 are used to keep a space for buttons and zoom control componenets (which all move and resize perfectly), zoomFactor is a double that hold the amount to zoom.

How do I resize the screenshotPanel inside the ScrollPane without the ScrollPane forcing it's size back?

Comment: flickering is caused from JViewport or JScrollBars or Borders or another ???, everything there will be only shots to the dark without an SSCCE

Comment: questions are you tried to use ImageIcon in JLabel, or you using BuferrefedImage, or scaledInstance (simply asynchronous)

Comment: you are right I should have mentioned, I am using a BufferedImage for the screenshotPanel's image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the size of the component won't scale the image, unless you have code in your paint method to compensate for the change in size.

`JViewPort` is respecting your components preferred size, thus you get this flicker, as you change the size and the viewport resets it.

Add a `scale` method to your panel and override the `getPreferredSize` method.

When you call `setScale`, calculate the new scaled size.  Make sure that the `getPreferredSize` method returns these values.

You will need to call `invalidate` and possibly `repaint` to make sure the change is updated through the container hierarchy.

Remember, the pane will not resize the image on it's own, you are responsible for taking this ;)